# Matplotlib.pyplot only displays final plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to create a simple 1 by 3 subplot of the maps I have. They only have 2 dimensions (longitude and latitude) after time averaging. The final map plots perfectly, but the first two subplots are just blank. 
Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xa
import cmocean.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

lgm = xa.open_dataset('lgm.nc', decode_times=False)
pre = xa.open_dataset('pre-i.nc', decode_times=False)
pd = xa.open_dataset('present.nc', decode_times=False)

def pco2_diff():
    lgm_pco2 = lgm.O_pco2sur
    pre_pco2 = pre.O_pco2sur
    pd_pco2 = pd.O_pco2sur

    #-------------------------Time averaged data-------------------------------
    lgm_pco2_mean = lgm_pco2.mean("time")
    pre_pco2_mean = pre_pco2.mean("time")
    pd_pco2_mean = pd_pco2.mean("time")

    #-----------------Get the ocean-atmosphere fluxes--------------------------
    lgm_pco2_diff = lgm_pco2_mean - 189.65
    pre_pco2_diff = pre_pco2_mean - 277.44
    pd_pco2_diff = pd_pco2_mean - 368.89

    #---------------------Basic plots, 1 at a time-----------------------------
    lgm_pco2_diff.plot()
    pre_pco2_diff.plot()
    pd_pco2_diff.plot()

    #-----------------------------Subplots-------------------------------------
    f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True, sharex=False)
    #1 row, 3 columns, sharing the y-axis, not sharing the x-axis
    ax1 = lgm_pco2_diff.plot(vmin=-300, vmax=300, add_colorbar=False)
    ax2 = pre_pco2_diff.plot(vmin=-300, vmax=300, add_colorbar=False)
    ax3 = pd_pco2_diff.plot(vmin=-300, vmax=300,cmap=cm.thermal)
```

Comment: `lgm_pco2_diff.plot(vmin=-300, vmax=300, add_colorbar=False, ax=ax1)` and similarly for the next two lines?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't "tag" your titles. SO has real tags, which you have used correctly here.

Comment: Please show [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case use some simple simulated data instead data that are only on your disc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try the following:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True, sharex=False)
ax1.plot(lgm_pco2_diff, vmin=-300, vmax=300, add_colorbar=False)
ax2.plot(pre_pco2_diff, vmin=-300, vmax=300, add_colorbar=False)
ax3.plot(pd_pco2_diff, vmin=-300, vmax=300, cmap=cm.thermal)
```